# Transform Data into 7bit instead 1 byte in C

Tags: c, embedded

I have a communication between a master and a slave node, where a message looks like this:

[2 byte header start][up to 11 byte payload][1 byte crc][2 byte header end]

There can now occur a problem, when in the payload the 2 header end bytes are included in the same order. The crc will prevent an error, but this command will never come through. So somehow I need to exclude the header delimiters from the payload, at least the two end delimiters, but I dont see how I can actually achieve that in an efficient way. My first tought was to use 7bit instead of 8bit, but then I can not build up an uint32_t, uint64_t.

Any ideas how I can tackle this problem?

Comment: Why can't you include the payload size in the header? In that way you will know exactly where the payload ends and the CRC starts. Also you won't need the "header end"

Comment: This question is not clearly phrased, but it seems you are trying to deal with the problem that the two bytes that denote the end of the message (which would be trailing bytes, not a header) could appear in the payload. There are many ways to solve that, and it is not clear why you think “converting to 7bit” would solve that. It is not even clear what that means. Perhaps it means formatting the payload with a zero bit and seven data bits in each byte, and ensuring at least one of the end marker bytes has its high bit set? That does seem fairly tedious.

Comment: May be, everything would become much easier if you would make the payload always 11 bytes long (e.g. fill up with 0s). Then your message would always contain 2 + 11 + 1 + 2 = 16 bytes and you hadn't any pain whatever payload contains...

Answer (score 0):

Well you can handle the end bits appearing in the payload by following method

In the header preceding the payload add the field for the length of payload if not already present so that end bits encountered before it are ignored. Alternatively you may make sure that the payload is always of 11 bytes of length (by using dummy zeros as @Scheff suggested) if you header no longer has the space to accommodate to length field.